# Active Directory Authentication for Subversion - not working

Tags: svn, active-directory, apache2.4

I'm trying to get my SVN running with Apache 2.4 and Active Directory.
I don't want to use a AuthzSVNAccessFile, I just want to use AD and mod_authnz_ldap.

I found the following config on several websites:

```
<Location /puppet/>
    AuthType basic
    AuthName "Subversion Puppet"
    AuthBasicProvider ldap

    AuthLDAPBindDN ldapbind@mydomain.de
    AuthLDAPBindPassword secretpassword
    AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://ldap01.mydomain.de:3269 ldap02.mydomain.de:3269/?sAMAccountName?sub"
    AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN off
    <RequireAll>
        <Limit MKACTIVITY PROPPATCH PUT CHECKOUT MKCOL MOVE COPY DELETE LOCK UNLOCK MERGE>
            # Read access
         <RequireAny>
           Require ldap-attribute memberOf="CN=RO-USERGROUP,OU=Subversion,OU=Groups,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=DE"
           Require ldap-attribute memberOf="CN=RW-USERGROUP,OU=Subversion,OU=Groups,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=DE"
         </RequireAny>
        </Limit>
        <LimitExcept MKACTIVITY PROPPATCH PUT CHECKOUT MKCOL MOVE COPY DELETE LOCK UNLOCK MERGE>
           # Write access
           Require ldap-attribute memberOf="CN=RW-USERGROUP,OU=Subversion,OU=Groups,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=DE"
        </LimitExcept>
    </RequireAll>

    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /srv/svn/puppet
    SVNListParentPath on
```

Now I have the following situation:

1. I can log in with the RW User.
2. I can not log in with the RO user.
3. If I comment the RW Part, I'm also able to login with the RO user.

The Logfile tells me this:

```
[Mon May 28 14:47:34.419982 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 32245] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client **.**.**.**:62762] AH01626: authorization result of Require ldap-attribute memberOf="ldap-attribute memberOf="CN=RW-USERGROUP,OU=Subversion,OU=Groups,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=DE": denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Mon May 28 14:47:34.420067 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 32245] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client **.**.**.**:62762] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAll>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Mon May 28 14:47:34.420140 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 32245] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client **.**.**.**:62762] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Mon May 28 14:47:34.420219 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 32245] mod_authz_core.c(728): [client **.**.**.**:62762] AH01625: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted (directive limited to other methods)
[Mon May 28 14:47:34.420294 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 32245] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client **.**.**.**:62762] AH01626: authorization result of Require ldap-attribute memberOf="ldap-attribute memberOf="CN=RW-USERGROUP,OU=Subversion,OU=Groups,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=DE": denied
[Mon May 28 14:47:34.420384 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 32245] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client **.**.**.**:62762] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAll>: denied
[Mon May 28 14:47:34.420464 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 32245] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client **.**.**.**:62762] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied
[Mon May 28 14:47:34.420537 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 32245] [client **.**.**.**:62762] AH01631: user ROuser: authorization failure for "/puppet/puppet2/environments":
[Mon May 28 14:47:34.420633 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 32245] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client **.**.**.**:62762] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Mon May 28 14:47:34.420713 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 32245] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client **.**.**.**:62762] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
```

So the AD Authentification is working, the Limit is doing a good Job (at least for the RW user), but there might be something wrong with the Require directive.

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody was answering I'm guessing nobody is interested in the answer.
I'm going to answer it anyways:

The upper block wasn't the READ block, it was the Write Block.
The lower block wasn't the WRITE block, it was the READ block.

So I've moved the Require ldap... of the RO user from the upper block to the lower block.

That's the block which is responsible for the limitation of the READ methods.

```
<Location /puppet/>
AuthType basic
AuthName "Subversion Puppet"
AuthBasicProvider ldap

AuthLDAPBindDN ldapbind@mydomain.de
AuthLDAPBindPassword secretpassword
AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://ldap01.mydomain.de:3269 ldap02.mydomain.de:3269/?sAMAccountName?sub"
AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN off
<RequireAll>
    <Limit MKACTIVITY PROPPATCH PUT CHECKOUT MKCOL MOVE COPY DELETE LOCK UNLOCK MERGE>
        # Write access
     <RequireAny>
       Require ldap-attribute memberOf="CN=RW-USERGROUP,OU=Subversion,OU=Groups,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=DE"
     </RequireAny>
    </Limit>
    <LimitExcept MKACTIVITY PROPPATCH PUT CHECKOUT MKCOL MOVE COPY DELETE LOCK UNLOCK MERGE>
       # Read access
       Require ldap-attribute memberOf="CN=RW-USERGROUP,OU=Subversion,OU=Groups,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=DE"
       Require ldap-attribute memberOf="CN=RO-USERGROUP,OU=Subversion,OU=Groups,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=DE"
    </LimitExcept>
</RequireAll>

DAV svn
SVNParentPath /srv/svn/puppet
SVNListParentPath on
```